# How do you split a string into a multidimensionnal array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, multidimensional-array

I have started to program in C# few weeks ago for work and I am trying to extract some information from big bunches of data, actually gathered by GET/POST http requests.

So far I have not had any problems with the whole but I am struggling now on this difficulty which, I am sure seems ridiculous to your eyes. That is why I am coming towards you, and no worries I have tryied to research it but without success.

Here is my list

```
[{"id":"28",
"name":"Whitechapel Station",
"logo":"gfx\/whitechapel_station\/whitechapel_station_logo.gif",
"x":"85129",
"y":"36575",
"extentsX1":"0",
"extentsX2":"0",
"extentsY1":"0",
"extentsY2":"0",
"zoomlevel":"4",
"code":"PRJ",
"asset_type":"fixed",
"symbol":"project"}

,{"id":"46",
"name":"Connaught Tunnel",
"logo":"gfx\/connaught_tunnel\/connaught_tunnel_logo.",
"x":"91668",
"y":"35238",
"extentsX1":"0",
"extentsX2":"0",
"extentsY1":"0",
"extentsY2":"0",
"zoomlevel":"4",
"code":"PRJ",
"asset_type":"fixed",
"symbol":"project"}
]
```

What I do have in mind actually is to extract only the "id" and the "name" of each bunch of big { }. Do you have any ideas ?

Cheers mates.

Clement

**EDIT: The code is not like normally like this. It is just one big straight line without returns as follows.**

```
[{"id":"28","name":"Whitechapel Station","logo":"gfx\/whitechapel_station\/whitechapel_station_logo.gif","x":"85129","y":"36575","extentsX1":"0","extentsX2":"0","extentsY1":"0","extentsY2":"0","zoomlevel":"4","code":"PRJ","asset_type":"fixed","symbol":"project"},{"id":"46","name":"Connaught Tunnel","logo":"gfx\/connaught_tunnel\/connaught_tunnel_logo.","x":"91668","y":"35238","extentsX1":"0","extentsX2":"0","extentsY1":"0","extentsY2":"0","zoomlevel":"4","code":"PRJ","asset_type":"fixed","symbol":"project"}]
```

Comment: This looks like something for JSON.Net.  Deserialize the string to an array of dictionaries.

Comment: multidimensional array?you don't need it..you can simply have a list of objects with name,id property

Comment: Definitely do as suggested by @JeremyHolovacs. The data JSON, use a JSON parser to extract what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample as you have posted it is in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.  In order to deserialize the JSOn string, you should use a tool like [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

First, make a c# object that matches the properties that you want to deserialze:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize:

```
var myObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(theString);
```

Then, the values will be available to you:

```
int id = myObjects[0].id;
string name = myObjects[0].name;
```

Comment: Isn't this more complex than it has to be?  Why make an object instead of a dictionary of key-value pairs?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Since the OP mentions several sources, I'm assuming that the JSON will change for each and this seems like the best way to define the data and then use it.  However, you could deserialize into many forms (including a dynamic).

Comment: that's my point... would you create a class for every permutation?  The only thing OP wants is the ID and Name values for these.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs With Json.NET if you leave off the properties, then just won't deserialize.  So, there is no need to create all properties from the json string.  All you need is an id and name.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.
Nonetheless, if I download the JSON package, does this mean that I will have to make my users download it as well to use the software I am making ? 
I really want to make my program as portable as possible.
Cheers !

Comment: @user2267162 Assuming that you will package your application under a directory, all of your application's dependencies will be shipped under the bin directory (usually).  If this is the case, the user will not have to download anything.

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks for this. Is it possible to install Json package on Visual Studio C# 2010 EXPRESS ?

Comment: @user2267162 Yes, it is just a dll reference (or NuGet package)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, basically I did a thick error.
I added the character " between each [ or ] and { or }.
SOLVED !